# How to uninstall perl installed via cpan which conflicts with yum

Tags: perl, cpan, yum

On my centos 6.3 server I installed perl via the `yum install perl` packager install

However, while installing `ExtUtils/Embed` via `cpan` cpan updated my Perl to v5.17.4 when it should be  5.10.1-127 (presumably some way via dependencies as I used the force install method).

So now i run into dozens of issues such as the error:

```
../x86_64-linux/CORE/libperl.a(op.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `PL_sv_yes' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Which I can't recompile with fpic because it was installed via cpan somehow. The compiler is using this new perl instead of the old compatible one which doesn't give me this error.

Is there a way I can uninstall this 5.17.4 perl? I've tried to use `pm-uninstall`.. etc to no avail. I've even tried `yum reinstall perl` yet the newer perl remains in use

Comment: Important - did you do all this as root? If not, you haven't overwritten your system perl.

Comment: This is a good example why you shouldn't use your system-installed perl for developing but install your own (e.g. with perlbrew)... not that that helps you now, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can't you reinstall 5.10.1 as your system perl?

Comment: For a server, I would recommend maintaining your own CPAN mirror that cpan/cpanp/cpanm are configured to use/ When you want to install a package, copy it to your mirror. Then you will avoid unexpected surprises.  I would also avoid installing modules as root. When possible, use local::lib modules for specific users that need them, to avoid interfering with the system Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't scrub everything, but should get you going again.

Record your installed perl rpms:

```
 rpm -qa | grep ^perl > /tmp/perlpkgs
```

Force remove them:

```
 for i in `cat /tmp/perlpkgs` ; do rpm -ev --nodeps $i ; done
```

Figure out where perl is installed in case cpan put it in `/usr/local`

```
 which perl
```

If it prints `/usr/local/bin/perl` then `P=/usr/local`; otherwise `P=/usr`

Remove any perl binaries, etc,

```
 rm -fr $P/bin/perl* $P/lib*/perl* $P/share/man/man?/perl*
 rm -fr $P/share/man/man?/*.3pm* $P/share/perl*
```

Reinstall all of the original packages:

```
 yum install `cat /tmp/perlpkgs`
```